# Communicate to an Azure service bus from a different subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-identity

I created a service bus for a learning purpose, and I want to pass messages to it. I went through the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=passwordless) which teaches to use the `DefaultAzureCredential`  so that the stored credentials in Visual Studio are gonna get used.

The problem is, I have logged in to Visual studio from my work email, which I use daily. And the new service bus is in a different subscription, and it's attached to my personal email.

So, is there a way to get the service bus to work, without logging in with my personal email, and CLI configurations? Any alternatives for this `DefaultAzureCredential` object?

Sample code (From Microsoft documentation)

```
ServiceBusClient client;
    
const int numOfMessages = 3;
var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions
{
    TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
};

client = new ServiceBusClient("asb-test.servicebus.windows.net",
            new DefaultAzureCredential(),
            clientOptions);

sender = client.CreateSender("email");
    
using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await 
   sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
    
var result = messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage($"Message"));

if (!result)
{
    throw new Exception($"The message is too large to fit in the batch.");
}
    
try
{
    await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"A batch of {numOfMessages} messages has been published to the queue.");
}
finally
{
     await sender.DisposeAsync();
     await client.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Look at the overloads for the ServiceBusClient constructor. There are other options.

Answer (score 0):

If the subscriptions are in the same tenant, this is not a problem, you can still easily assign permissions. But I guess what you mean to say is that the subs are in two different tenants.

You could try to add your work account as a guest user in your personal tenant, then you should also be able to assign it permissions.